# Ingesting Data from Hive to GeoMesa Accumulo

Tags: jdbc, hive, geomesa

I'm attempting to ingest data from Hive into GeoMesa Accumulo using a JDBC converter. Here is the configuration I have for the JDBC converter:

```
geomesa.converters.hive  = {    
  type = "jdbc",   
  connection = "jdbc:hive2://host:10000/default",
  id-field = "$1",
  fields = [
    { name = "my_id", type = "string", transform = "$1" },
    { name = "shape", type = "geometry", transform = "geometry($2)" }
  ]
}
```

To ingest the data, I use the following command:

```
echo "SELECT * FROM table" | geomesa-accumulo ingest -u user -p pass -c catalog -s hive.sft -f feature -C hive.conf
```

Despite having copied the Hive JDBC driver to the GeoMesa library, I encounter the following error when running the above command:

```
2023-09-13 10:51:59,640 WARN  [org.locationtech.geomesa.convert2.package$ErrorHandlingIterator] Failed parsing input: 
java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: Method not supported
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.prepareCall(HiveConnection.java:1215)
    at org.locationtech.geomesa.convert.jdbc.JdbcConverter$StatementIterator.hasNext(JdbcConverter.scala:86)
    at org.locationtech.geomesa.convert2.package$ErrorHandlingIterator.liftedTree1$1(package.scala:84)
    at org.locationtech.geomesa.convert2.package$ErrorHandlingIterator.hasNext(package.scala:83)
    at org.locationtech.geomesa.convert.jdbc.JdbcConverter$ResultSetIterator.hasNext(JdbcConverter.scala:119)
    at org.locationtech.geomesa.utils.collection.CloseableIterator$FlatMapCloseableIterator.hasNext(CloseableIterator.scala:140)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:943)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:943)
    at org.locationtech.geomesa.utils.collection.CloseableIterator$FlatMapCloseableIterator.foreach(CloseableIterator.scala:132)
    at org.locationtech.geomesa.tools.ingest.LocalConverterIngest$LocalIngestWorker.$anonfun$run$7(LocalConverterIngest.scala:179)
    at org.locationtech.geomesa.tools.ingest.LocalConverterIngest$LocalIngestWorker.$anonfun$run$7$adapted(LocalConverterIngest.scala:173)
    at org.locationtech.geomesa.utils.io.CloseablePool$CommonsPoolPool.borrow(CloseablePool.scala:68)
    at org.locationtech.geomesa.tools.ingest.LocalConverterIngest$LocalIngestWorker.$anonfun$run$6(LocalConverterIngest.scala:173)
    at org.locationtech.geomesa.tools.ingest.LocalConverterIngest$LocalIngestWorker.$anonfun$run$6$adapted(LocalConverterIngest.scala:172)
    at org.locationtech.geomesa.utils.io.package$WithClose$.apply(package.scala:64)
    at org.locationtech.geomesa.tools.ingest.LocalConverterIngest$LocalIngestWorker.$anonfun$run$4(LocalConverterIngest.scala:172)
    at org.locationtech.geomesa.tools.ingest.LocalConverterIngest$LocalIngestWorker.$anonfun$run$4$adapted(LocalConverterIngest.scala:168)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:943)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:943)
    at org.locationtech.geomesa.utils.collection.CloseableIterator$CloseableSingleIterator.foreach(CloseableIterator.scala:85)
    at org.locationtech.geomesa.tools.ingest.LocalConverterIngest$LocalIngestWorker.$anonfun$run$3(LocalConverterIngest.scala:168)
    at org.locationtech.geomesa.tools.ingest.LocalConverterIngest$LocalIngestWorker.$anonfun$run$3$adapted(LocalConverterIngest.scala:167)
    at org.locationtech.geomesa.utils.io.package$WithClose$.apply(package.scala:64)
    at org.locationtech.geomesa.tools.ingest.LocalConverterIngest$LocalIngestWorker.$anonfun$run$2(LocalConverterIngest.scala:167)
    at org.locationtech.geomesa.tools.ingest.LocalConverterIngest$LocalIngestWorker.$anonfun$run$2$adapted(LocalConverterIngest.scala:166)
    at org.locationtech.geomesa.utils.io.CloseablePool$CommonsPoolPool.borrow(CloseablePool.scala:68)
    at org.locationtech.geomesa.tools.ingest.LocalConverterIngest$LocalIngestWorker.run(LocalConverterIngest.scala:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

Does anyone have insights into resolving this issue?

Comment: auliama, As moderator, I've dropped the marginally related hadoop and accumulo tags. Since the question is one of geomesa, and not one for users following hadoop and accumulo topics more generally, I've removed those tags from your question. Please try to use tags to attract the audience most suitable to answering your questions. A developer following the accumulo topic, for example, will not know the answer to your geomesa-specific question, so you should not tag accumulo.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug in GeoMesa. It should be calling `prepareStatement` instead of `prepareCall`, although both seem to work with other databases (e.g. Postgresql). I've opened a ticket to track the issue [here](https://geomesa.atlassian.net/browse/GEOMESA-3296).

If possible, you could try changing [this line](https://github.com/locationtech/geomesa/blob/geomesa-4.0.2/geomesa-convert/geomesa-convert-jdbc/src/main/scala/org/locationtech/geomesa/convert/jdbc/JdbcConverter.scala#L86) to use `prepareStatement`,  [building from source](https://github.com/locationtech/geomesa#building-from-source), and then see if that fixes the issue for you.

Comment: I put up an PR with the proposed fix here: https://github.com/locationtech/geomesa/pull/2995